# MVC URL Redirection

Tags: url, model-view-controller, routes

We have 2 web sites. Two web sites were hosted in different LAN.
For example

Server 1 : http://10.106.15.27:1220/Master/LogIn

Server 2 : http://10.105.27.1221/Accounts/LogIn

Users can access Server 1 only and cant access Server 2 due to some restrictions.

Now i want to redirect server 2 web Page in Server 1 like

http://10.106.15.27:1220/External/Accounts/LogIn in my MVC . So Other users will see Server 2 from Server 1.

How can i route like this in my MVC ?

Comment: can you provide more information ? which language your mvc is build with ? which web servers are u using ?

Comment: I am using MVC5 . I am hosting files in IIS. Both were Windows servers .